# Python socket blocks on "[Errno -2] Name or service not known"?

Tags: python, sockets, tornado, nonblocking

I'm running non-blocking sockets asynchronously in a Tornado IOLoop. But, in spite of this, a block sometimes occurs (as evidenced by 0% CPU), and always results in an `Errorno -2 Name or service not known`.

Why does this happen?

It blocks for about five seconds (more than twice the timeout at least). There are perhaps 15-30 open sockets at any given time, reused with the `setsockopt` flag.

Socket:

```
    # make connection   
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.settimeout(2) # 2 seconds timeout

    ioloop.add_callback(self.connect, s)
```

Tornado errorwarning:

```
WARNING:tornado.general:Connect error on fd 23: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the Answer, but I think it helped (see third paragraph):

```
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.settimeout(2) # 2 seconds timeout

        streamloop.add_callback(self.connect, s)

        # added this to close sockets completely after use. might help.
        l_onoff = 1
        l_linger = 0
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack('ii', l_onoff, l_linger))
```